# Swift SpriteKit SKEmitter node color not correct when added to the scene

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, particle-system, skemitternode

I made a particle system in the particle editor in Xcode and it came out like this.

[image]

I set it up in my SpriteKit scene like this.

```
    emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Trail.sks")!
    emitter.particleColor = .red
    effectNode.addChild(emitter)
    lastPointNode.addChild(effectNode)
    emitter.position = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)
    emitter.targetNode = self
```

Everything worked out fine except that it shows up in the scene as this wierd, pink color that is not at all like the original color and i can't seem to fix it.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try a blend mode other than add?

Comment: @bg2b Yes, but i don't like how they look. Only add gives me this blend from white to the original color, kind of like a lightsaber

Comment: Using screen makes a similar look and looks the same when run but it is not as clean and I don't see why add doesn't look the same as in the editor it makes no sense

Comment: How is the curving happening? I don't see anything in the emitter that would do something like that. I was asking about add since it seems like the red when being crossed over with some of the central white might give the pinkish tinge under that blend mode.

Comment: Im just changing the position of the emitter node as the user drags on the screen. Im not that familiar with the blend modes but I just don't understand why it is not the same in the editor and on the scene. Even if the pinkish color is correct, shouldn't it show that in the editor too?

Comment: Are you dragging it in the editor as well? (I do emitters in code, not the editor, so don't know whether you can drag there). Another idea is that since the editor display is not in a normal game, maybe the background that it's blending into is different. You could wrap an SKEffectNode around the emitter and see if that looks better (the idea being that the emitter can use add to build up the lightsaber effect, then you can blend it separately into the scene with the emitter's blend mode).

Comment: would you mind providing me with a little bit of code? I don't know what you mean by using the emitter's blend mode to blend it separately into the scene. I think thats what I was trying to do with the effectnode but i never actually figured out how to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207054/discussion-between-bg2b-and-repardeimaj).